# Seeking for another proof that a Hausdorff space is not always regular.

Tags: general-topology

Let $a$ be a point of $X$ and let $B$ be a closed set of $X$ disjoint from $a$. The Hausdorff condition enables us to choose, for each $b$ in $B$, an open set $U_b$ about $b$ whose closure is disjoint from $a$. Let $D = \cup{Cl (U_b)}$. I tried a lot (but failed) to show that the interior of $D$ covers $B$ and the closure of $D$ is disjoint from $a$ without imposing locally finite condition, so arriving at a weaker conditions that is only by being a Hausdorff. So why (= proof) not the interior of $D$ covers $B$ and the closure of $D$ is disjoint from $a$?

Comment: One counterexample is all the proof we need. There is no other way to disprove an implication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof idea comes down to :

$a \notin B$, $B$ closed. For every $b \in B$, pick $U(b)$ open such that $a \notin \overline{U(b)}$, which can be done as we have disjoint neighbourhoods of $A$ and $b$ and we pick the one for $b$ and the one for $a$ witnesses the not being in the closure of the other.

Now you define $D = \cup\{\overline{U(b)}: b \in B\}$. This $D$ is not in general closed (as an arbitary union of closed sets need not be).
The interior $\operatorname{int}(D)$ contains $\cup\{U(b): b \in B\}$ so does cover $B$ by definition, but it's very possibly the case that $a \in \overline{D}$ (e.g. conceivably every $U(b)$ could contain a different point of some dense subset of $X$ and then their union would be dense). If indeed the $U(b)$ could be chosen locally finite (or finite as for compact $B$), $D$ *would* be closed and all would be well in this proof attempt.

To show that a Hausdorff space need not be regular, you don't have to show that one possible proof idea does not work; that might only show you haven't come up with a proof yet. It suffices to find one example $X$ of a space that is Hausdorff but not regular. Take any such space $X$ (Pick your favourite
among [these](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=%24T_2%24%2B%7ERegular)) pick a closed set $B$ in it and $a \notin B$ where regular fails, and see how your proof fails in that particular case; it might help your intuition.